# Text File Binary Search

Tags: c++, search, fstream, seekg

I have a test file that looks like this:

```
Ampersand           Gregorina           5465874526370945
Anderson            Bob                 4235838387422002
Anderson            Petunia             4235473838457294
Aphid               Bumbellina          8392489357392473
Armstrong-Jones     Mike                8238742438632892
```

And code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class CardSearch
{
protected:
    std::ifstream cardNumbers;

public:
    CardSearch(std::string fileName)
    {
        cardNumbers.open(fileName, std::ios::in);

        if (!cardNumbers.is_open())
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to open: " << fileName;
        }
        return;
    }

    std::string Find(std::string lastName, std::string firstName)
    {
        // Creating string variables to hold first and last name
        // as well as card number. Also creating bools to decide whether
        // or not the person has been found or if the last name is the only
        // identifier for a found person
        std::string lN;
        std::string fN;
        std::string creditNumber;
        bool foundPerson = false;

        // By using the seekg and tellg functions, we can find our place
        // in the file and also calculate the amount of lines within the file
        cardNumbers.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        cardNumbers.clear();
        std::streamsize first = cardNumbers.tellg();
        cardNumbers.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
        cardNumbers.clear();
        std::streamsize last = cardNumbers.tellg();
        cardNumbers.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        std::streamsize lineNumbers = (last / 57);
        std::streamsize middle;

        while (first <= lineNumbers)
        {
            middle = (first + lineNumbers) / 2;
            // middle * 57 takes us to the beginning of the correct line
            cardNumbers.seekg(middle * 57, std::ios::beg);
            cardNumbers.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

            cardNumbers >> lN >> fN;

            if (lN < lastName)
            {
                first = middle + 1;
            }
            else if (lN > lastName)
            {
                lineNumbers = middle - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (fN < firstName)
                {
                    first = middle + 1;
                }
                else if (fN > firstName)
                {
                    lineNumbers = middle - 1;
                }
                else if (fN == firstName)
                {
                    foundPerson = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundPerson)
        {
            // When a person is found, we seek to the correct line position and 
            // offset by another 40 characters to receive the card number
            cardNumbers.seekg((middle * 57) + 40, std::ios::beg);
            std::cout << lN << ", " << fN << " ";
            cardNumbers >> creditNumber;
            return creditNumber;
        }
        return "Unable to find person.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    CardSearch CS("C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/StolenNumbers.txt");
    std::string S = CS.Find("Ampersand", "Gregorina");
    std::cout << S;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I am able to retrieve all but the first record in the list. It seems as though the seekg is seeking to the correct position but cardNumbers is not reading the correct information. When 'middle' is set to 0, the seekg should seek to the 0th line, (middle * 57), read in Ampersand Gregorina and make a comparison. Instead, it remains reading Anderson Bob.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: This middle? `middle = (first + lineNumbers) / 2;`

Comment: @rafa Your entire approach is flawed.  The big mistake is that you're using `seekg` on a file opened in text mode.  You can't use such functions reliably when you've opened a file this way.  The `seekg` works as you would expect on files opened in binary `ios:binary` mode.  The reason why your code is doomed for failure is that in text mode, translations are done for line end-of-line and EOF, which you do not know about and would not want to keep track of (you would lose your sanity if you tried).  If you're going to do this, open the file in binary mode and work it out from there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Your solution was correct and has allowed me to progress. Now, I have an issue with Armstrong-Jones Mike. When middle is set to 4, it instead reads '73' from the last line for the last name, and Mike on the correct line for the first line. Because of this, it shows as unable to find the correct record

Comment: @rafa I posted my suggestion to you as the answer to the `seekg` issue.  So you're saying there is a further issue?  If so, then maybe another question should be posted?  Also, how did you come up with the magic number of 57?

Comment: doesnt your stream.ignore skip characters till it reaches \n. ie it will never read the first line

Comment: @rafa - You have to include in the line count the end-of-line character sequence (carriage return / line feed for Windows, line feed for Linux).  Your 57 is off by 1 or 2 bytes.  It probably should be 58 or 59.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You were right. I added 1 to make it 58 and it works as expected. Thanks for all of guidance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

LineNumbers is being modified by your loop going from 4, to 1, to -1.  The -1 makes your loop terminate too early so you don't pick up the first entry properly.

It seems like a homework problem, so I hope you can use this to direct yourself towards an answer.

Comment: It should not go that far. When middle is 0, seekg should take it to the first line which is the correct record I'm looking for. On the second loop, when LineNumbers is still 1, middle is 0 but incorrectly reading the name. It should be the first record, but instead, it reads record 2, which is Anderson Bob

Answer (score 0):

When using functions such as `seekg`, it is always best to open the file in `binary mode`, not text mode as your code is doing now.  In other words, you should be doing this:

```
cardNumbers.open(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

The reason is that opening a file in text mode will allow end-of-line translations to be done.  This renders functions such as `seekg`, `tellg`, etc. anything between unstable (or lucky to work) at best, and in the worst case, useless for text processing.

When a file is opened in binary mode, the `seekg` and other family of functions  work as expected, since there are no end-of-line translations being done.  You will actually seek to the byte offset in the file that you specify, and not be thrown off by end-of-line translations.

Also, once you do this, the length of the data in the line includes not only the visible text, but also the invisible characters that make up the end-of-line sequence.  So your hand calculation of 57 is not going to be correct in binary mode -- it should be 58 or 59, depending on whether you are using Linux / Unix, or Windows, respectively.