# Writing on last line with fstream

Tags: c++, string, file, c++11, fstream

I was trying to replace a string in a text file. Something like replace() function.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
Using namespace std;
int main()
{

fstream file("C:\\Users\\amir hossein\\Desktop\\Temp1\\test1.txt");

char *sub; sub = new char[20]; sub = "amir";
char *replace1; replace1 = new char[20]; replace1 = "reza";
char *buffer; buffer = new char[100];


int i, temp; streampos flag;
int c=0,mark;
bool flagforwrite=0;


if (file.is_open()){
    while (!file.eof()) {
        flag = file.tellg();
        file.getline(buffer, 100);    //We'll Search Sub inside of Buffer, if true, we'll replace it with Replace string
        flagforwrite=0;
        for (i=0;buffer[i];i++){
            mark=i; c=0;
            while (sub[c] && sub[c]== buffer[mark]){
                c++; mark++;
            }

            if (!sub[c]){   //Make Changes in The Line
                for (int j=i,count=0;count<strlen(replace1);j++,count++) buffer[j] = replace1[count]; //until here, we've replace1d the sub
                flagforwrite=1;
            }

        }

        if (flagforwrite){   //Write The line ( After Whole Changes In line have been made!!
                file.seekp(flag);
                file << buffer << "\n";   // ENDL here IS SUPER IMPORTANT!! IF you don't put it, I'll mess it up
                if(file.bad()) cout << "Error\n";
        }
    }
}

else cout << "Error!!\n";
file.close();  
delete[] sub;
delete[] replace1;
delete[] buffer;


return 0;
}
```

I want to replace "amir" with "reza".

My text file includes 4 lines:

> Hi My name is amir and also my friend's name is amir too!
>      Hi My name is amir and also my friend's name is amir too!
>      Hi My name is amir and also my friend's name is amir too!
>      Hi My name is amir and also my friend's name is amir too!

When I run the program I get this.

> Hi My name is reza and also my friend's name is reza too!
>      Hi My name is reza and also my friend's name is reza too!
>      Hi My name is reza and also my friend's name is reza too!
>      Hi My name is amir and also my friend's name is amir too!

What is wrong with the last line?

I think that problem is here:

```
if (flagforwrite){ 
                    file.seekp(flag);
                    file << buffer << "\n";
                    if(file.bad()) cout << "Error\n";
            }
```

Why is the flag always referring to the line?

I'm using GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: ` while (!file.eof()) {` <- This is wrong (although I don't know whether it would actually cause this problem)

Comment: `file.seekp(flag);`  You opened the file in text mode.  Using functions such as `seekp` will not give you the desired results.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926595/text-file-binary-search  If you want to process the file with any modicum of success, open the file in binary mode (`ios::binary`).

Comment: Never do this: `while (!file.eof())`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong it often messes up the last line.

Comment: Please write C++ code, instead of C code that uses C++. You're leaking memory, and you shouldn't even be allocating memory in the first place, rather using std::string, which supports all string operations that are manually implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem! It was caused by eof()! 
so Instead of using `while(!file.eof())` I used `while(file.getline(buffer,100))`

and I also Moved file.tellg() to the end, and defined line like this: `streampos line=file.tellg();`